# i want to create a copy to clipboard using react js

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to create copy to clip board using react js but i design like 
textbox with in contain 'copy' word ,when i click this copy word it changed to be copied 
and the textbox value will be copied

Answer (score 1):

For clipboard interaction in React, I use [clipboard-polyfil](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clipboard-polyfill).  It is nice because it provides polyfills to work on all browsers, which some of the native clipboard functions do not, such as `document.execCommand("copy")` and `navigator.clipboard.write()`.

The easiest way to use this package with react is to make a custom component, pass in the string you would like to copy as a prop, and copy it using `clipboard.writeText(this.props.stringValue);`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using `ref`, `document.execCommand('copy')`.

```
import React from 'react';

class CopyExample extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { copySuccess: '' }
  }

  copyToClipboard = (e) => {
    this.textArea.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    e.target.focus();
    this.setState({ copySuccess: 'Copied!' });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
         document.queryCommandSupported('copy') &&
          <div>
            <button onClick={this.copyToClipboard}>Copy</button> 
            {this.state.copySuccess}
          </div>
        }
        <form>
          <textarea
            ref={(textarea) => this.textArea = textarea}
            value='Some text to copy'
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default CopyExample;
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'm using [react-copy-to-clipboard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-copy-to-clipboard)

1- install it using npm:

`npm install --save react react-copy-to-clipboard`

2- import it to your file:

`import {CopyToClipboard} from 'react-copy-to-clipboard';`

3- now you can wrap your component with `<CopyToClipboard>` component

it also provide `onCopy` optional callback function.

resources: [CopyToClipboard repo on github](https://github.com/nkbt/react-copy-to-clipboard)